# may be its related to Jump server

Tags: linux, autojump

I am very much confused with the environment I am newly working with. Can any one give me a elaborative idea about this please.

step 1: I am logging into the server by passing the hostname as "ujump" in Putty.

Step2: Using my LDAP id to login into the session.

Step3: using command `ssh xtabidv2` to login to another server named "ssz0287" (its the hostname)

> > login as: pbehf
> >
> > password:
> >
> > pbehf@lxv0734 [/home/pbehf] $ ssh xtabidv2
> >
> > password:
> >
> > pbehf@ssz0287 [/home/pbehf] $ -->
> >
> > pbehf@ssz0287 [/home/pbehf] $ --> hostname
> >
> > ssz0287
> >
> > pbehf@ssz0287 [/home/pbehf] $ -->

Here the homepath "/hosme/pbehf" is same though I am doing ssh to another server. If I will change anything under my this Homepath, it will reflect every where.

lets check this as well;

> > pbehf@ssz0287 [/home/pbehf] $ -->
> >
> > pbehf@ssz0287 [/home/pbehf] $ --> ssh xtabidv1
> >
> > Password:
> >
> > pbehf@ssz0292 [/home/pbehf] $ --> hostname
> >
> > ssz0292
> >
> > pbehf@ssz0292 [/home/pbehf] $ --> pwd
> >
> > /home/pbehf

Still the same homepath. And if I will change here anything now, that too will reflect in all my Homepath. This pretends to the same homepath I am being landed firstly irrespective of `ssh` server.

Can anyone please let me understand the concept here.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `mount | grep home`

Comment: Could you please reformulate the question such that it is clear what you are actually asking? Your question _Can anyone please let me understand the concept here._ is simply too vague.

Answer (score 0):

With `ssh` you connect to another server. Since you do not specify which user you are connected to the same user. You mentioned that you use LDAP to authenticate. In LDAP you define your home directory. It is therefore obvious that you end up in the same home directory on each server. If you change something in that directory and this is visible on the other servers too then your home directory is mounted from a file-server. You can check this with `df -h`. This gives you an overview of all file systems that are mounted. I guess that you will find your home directory in that list.